# Format String as phone number in C#

Tags: c#

I have a string value 1233873600 in C# and I have to convert it to 123-387-7300 in C#

Is there any in-built function which will do that in c#?

Comment: no there isn't, but you can easily write your own.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format a string as a telephone number in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188510/how-to-format-a-string-as-a-telephone-number-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use regex for this. The regex for North America phone number looks like this

```
^(\(?[0-9]{3}\)?)?\-?[0-9]{3}\-?[0-9]{4}$
```

I guess you can use `Regex.Replace` method in C#.

Comment: using a format string would be the preferred method of doing this.
both more readable and computationally faster.

Answer (score 12):

Cast your string to a long and use the format `"{0:### ### ####}"`;

```
string.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", 1112223333);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string phone = "1233873600".Insert(6, "-").Insert(3, "-");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple helper method that will take the string, sterilize the input in order to remove spaces or unwanted special characters being used as a separator, and then use the ToString method built-in. If you check for various lengths you can also assure the format comes out as you see fit. For example:

```
public string FormatPhoneNumber(string phoneNumber)
    {
        string originalValue = phoneNumber;

        phoneNumber= new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\D")
            .Replace(phoneNumber, string.Empty);

        value = value.TrimStart('1');

        if (phoneNumber.Length == 7)

            return Convert.ToInt64(value).ToString("###-####");
        if (phoneNumber.Length == 9)

            return Convert.ToInt64(originalValue).ToString("###-###-####");
        if (phoneNumber.Length == 10)

            return Convert.ToInt64(value).ToString("###-###-####");

        if (phoneNumber.Length > 10)
            return Convert.ToInt64(phoneNumber)
                .ToString("###-###-#### " + new String('#', (phoneNumber.Length - 10)));

        return phoneNumber;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think regex is the best option.

this site is great for finding pre made regex strings.

http://www.regexlib.com/

Answer (score 0):

String Format didn't work for me, so I did:

```
string nums = String.Join("", numbers);
return nums.Insert(0, "(").Insert(4, ")").Insert(5, " ").Insert(9, "-");
```