# mvc3 format phone number

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to display the phone number like this  (999) 999-9999  I thought the css class would do this but it doesn't

```
<td>@Html.Encode(Model.PhoneModel.PhoneNumber)</td>.
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work

```
@String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}",Model.PhoneModel.PhoneNumber.ToString())
```

Comment: Doesn't `@Html.Encode` just print (an admittedly encoded) string? What are you trying to add a class to?

Comment: actually what I'm trying to do is format the phone number like this  (999) 999-9999

Comment: how does it comes to the Proeprty ? without brackets and hiphen ?

Comment: Shyju yes just numbers no formatting

Comment: @RonaldMcDonald: Please mention your requirements clearly in the first version of question. People get confused and you may not get the answer you are looking for

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format a string as a telephone number in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188510/how-to-format-a-string-as-a-telephone-number-in-c-sharp)

Comment: _I tried this, but it doesn't work_ How didn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work, but I don't like the fact that it's regrex.

```
@Regex.Replace(Model.PhoneModel.PhoneNumber, @"(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})", "($1) $2-$3")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at changing how you are outputting the values.  Consider this article from Phil Haack.

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/28/replacing-html-encode.aspx

EDIT:
To address your edit of formatting as a phone number reference this thread:
[How to format a string as a telephone number in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188510/how-to-format-a-string-as-a-telephone-number-in-c-sharp)

```
String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", 8005551212);
```

Comment: Yes.  Correct.  That is no longer needed since MVC2

Answer (score 0):

There's not much point in spending too much effort on formatting phone numbers, when others have done all the work for you.  Check out http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/ for a library which will format numbers (and convert them back to a standard format) for you.  It's also available on nuget as libphonenumber-csharp.