# format a string as phone in a linq query

Tags: vb.net, linq, string-formatting

why wont this work, I am trying to format the phone as a standard

```
Dim Patient = From line In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("K:\PAT02.txt")
Select New With { _
Key .PatientID = line.substring(0,7).trim, _
.FirstName = line.substring(7,11).trim, _
.MiddleName = line.substring(18,1).trim, _
.LastName = line.substring(19,15).trim, _
.Home = (String.Format("{0:(###)###-####}", line.substring(112,10).trim)), _        
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Error message? Exception?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188510/how-to-format-a-string-as-a-telephone-number-in-c-sharp the title here is mentioning Linq but actually Linq is not involved at all in the mentioned problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra comma at the end of your `New With` block, remove it and your code will compile.

About your phone number problem, you're using number formatting, so you must pass a number to the `String.Format` method:

```
.Home = String.Format("{0:(###)###-####}", CLng(line.substring(112,10).trim))
```

Comment: Done and that does not work, that expression is actually the cut down version that line .Home = (String.Format("{0:(###)###-####}", line.substring(112,10).trim)) _  inly returns the contents of line.substring(112,10).trim))

Comment: I just wrote a separate function and it seems to have done the job