# How can I use placeholders for characters in a string?

Tags: c#

I am trying to use the solution provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188510/how-to-format-a-string-as-a-telephone-number-in-c-sharp#), and have also referenced [this article](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/).

Basically, I am trying to format a social security number. This is the method used in the articles linked above:

```
String.Format(“{0:###-##-####}”, 123456789);
```

This works great when the number is passed in as shown above, but the number I need to format is contained in a string - so I am essentially doing this (which doesn't work):

```
String.Format(“{0:###-##-####}”, "123456789");
```

What is a good way to get around my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse the string to numeric type and then use `string.Format` like:

```
String.Format("{0:###-##-####}", long.Parse("123456789"));
```

You can also use [`long.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or `int.TryParse` based on your number, and then use that value in string.Format.

```
long number;
string str = "123456789";
if (!long.TryParse(str, out number))
{
    //invalid number
}

string formattedStr = String.Format("{0:###-##-####}", number);
```

Comment: What if the SSN has letters?

Comment: How do you know it is SSN ?

Comment: I am not sure if that's a relevant use case though.

Comment: "Basically, I am trying to format a social security number."

Comment: @LewsTherin, I missed that, but if the OP is trying to format the SSN, then I can only assume that it is number and it requires formatting, if it is already formatted, then there is no point in using `String.Format`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex.Replace method

```
string formatted = Regex.Replace("123456789", @"(.{3})(.{2})(.{4})", "$1-$2-$3");
```

Given you have not so many digits (or letters), you can use multiple dots.

```
string formatted = Regex.Replace("123456789", @"(...)(..)(....)", "$1-$2-$3");
```

Comment: Yes, It works even if the number consists of a mix of letters and digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to print single character

```
 string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", "123".ToCharArray().Cast<object>().ToArray())
```

Modify this code to support variable length of SSN (if it's necessary - build format string in runtime).

Answer (score 0):

SSN are normally stored in varchar. If so, you can use like this utility method.

```
public static string FormatSSN(string ssn)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ssn))
        return string.Empty;

    if (ssn.Length != 9)
        return ssn;

    string first3 = ssn.Substring(0, 3);
    string middle2 = ssn.Substring(6, 2);
    string last4 = ssn.Substring(5, 4);

    return string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", first3, middle2, last4);
}
```