# How to format phone numbers to datagridview from a textbox in VB

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a program that has 3 items in the form. A phone number textbox, datagridview, and a button. I want to be able to click the button and transfer the numbers from the phone number textbox to the datagridview, but instead of the numbers showing up like this: 1234567891 in the datagridview. I want the format of the phone numbers showing up like this (123) 123 – 1234. I’ve searched for hours on the internet, but I couldn’t figure out a good way to do this.

Comment: why don't you use a masked textbox instead of a normal one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format a string as a telephone number in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188510/how-to-format-a-string-as-a-telephone-number-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want the DataGridView to *store* the number as unformatted but *display* it as formatted. I'm not sure if you can do that or not, but the good news is, you don't need to. Why not simply store the unformatted number however you want and then pass the DataGridView the formatted number using a separate variable?

```
Dim UnformattedNumber As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim FormattedNumber As String = FormatNumber(UnformattedNumber)

Public Function FormatNumber(ByVal PhoneNumber As String) As String
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PhoneNumber) _
    AndAlso len(PhoneNumber) = 10 _
    AndAlso IsNumeric(PhoneNumber) Then
        FormatNumber = "(" & Left(PhoneNumber, 3) & ") " _
        & Mid(PhoneNumber, 4, 3) & " - " _
        & Right(PhoneNumber, 4)
    Else
        FormatNumber = ""
    End If
End Function
```

You can still refer to `UnformattedNumber` from a DataGridView event if you need to.

Note that if you place this function inside a Form, you will need to preface `Left` and `Right` with `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.`.