# How to format a string into a certain pattern?

Tags: c#, string

I have a string of telephone number. The format I wanted to use is like this

> (044) 463-2256

How can I format my string like this?

```
string tel = "0444632256";
var match = Regex.Replace(tel, @"");
```

I tried using Regex.Replace but I don't know what the format that I will put in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Length of the string is always constant(10) , then wecan use the below method to format

```
string tel = "0444632256";
var format = $"({tel.Substring(0, 3)}) {tel.Substring(3, 3)}-{tel.Substring(6, 4)}";
Console.WriteLine(format);
```

Comment: How can I remove the format text has been formated?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this

Comment: I placed this code on my unfocused event. My focused event's function is to remove the format so that when I edit the string it always formatted when I unfocused

Answer (score 0):

You can see below answer:

```
Convert.ToInt64(tel).ToString("###-###-#### ####")
```

[How to format a string as a telephone number in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188510/how-to-format-a-string-as-a-telephone-number-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Is the Customer Phone is where I place the telephone number?

Comment: Yes, also I've modified for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
string tel = "0444632256";
tel=String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", Int64.Parse(tel));
```

Output:

> (44) 463-2256