# Formating a string (mask?)

Tags: c#

I found that with long.Parse, ToString can take argument and I can format it to desired string, for example.

```
Input:    
Console.WriteLine(long.Parse("123").ToString("#-#-#"));

Output:
1-2-3
```

I wanted to do something similar with string, lets say I wanna parse string to format ####-###-####. Is there any way to do it without regex with one liner like example above?

EDIT

Ok, so I may be misunderstood, I didn't want to parse numbers, but string instead. I can do in python like:

'{}-{}-{}'.format(*'abc') and I will receive a-b-c. In C# it seems to work only with numbers.

Comment: Do you mean String.Format?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188510/how-to-format-a-string-as-a-telephone-number-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Jophyjob I mean something like aaaabbbcccc to aaa-bbb-ccc

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson I tried, but I wanna change format of string, and everywhere I found are numbers :/

Comment: Voting to reopen as the proposed dupe covers digits only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");

            Console.WriteLine("helloWorld".ToPhoneNumber("###-###-####"));
        }
    }

    public static class AdvancedFormatString
    {    
        public static string ToPhoneNumber(this string strArg, string outputformat)
        {
            if (outputformat == null)
                return strArg;

            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            var i = 0;

            foreach (var c in outputformat)
            {
                if (c == '#')
                {
                    if (i < strArg.Length)
                    {
                        sb.Append(strArg[i]);
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(c);
                }
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```