# Add special characters to string value to display Fax Number using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have string value like below example for fax

```
string fax="1111111111";
```

I need below result for above string to add special character for fax format like below.

```
(111)-111-1111
```

my code for reference because my question going down please help any to get result

```
        var list = (dynamic)null;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(faxdos.medicalRecordsFax) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(faxdos.fax))
        {

            list = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
          new SelectListItem{ Text=String.Format("{0:(###)-###-####}", faxdos.medicalRecordsFax)+" - Medical Records Fax", Value = faxdos.medicalRecordsFax},
          new SelectListItem{ Text=String.Format("{0:(###)-###-####}", faxdos.fax), Value = faxdos.fax },
        };
        }
        else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(faxdos.medicalRecordsFax))
        {
            list = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
          new SelectListItem{ Text=String.Format("{0:(###)-###-####}", faxdos.medicalRecordsFax)+" - Medical Records Fax", Value = faxdos.medicalRecordsFax},

        };
        }
        else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(faxdos.fax))
        {
            list = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
          new SelectListItem{ Text=String.Format("{0:(###)-###-####}", faxdos.fax), Value = faxdos.fax },
        };
        }
        else
        {
            list = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
          new SelectListItem{ Text="", Value = "" },
        };
        }
        // ViewBag.emp = list;
        var result = new SelectList(list, "Text", "Value");
        

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Generally, in North America, you'd format that as `(111) 111-1111`, i.e., using a space instead of the first dash

Comment: my client have requirement to display like this in the dropdown list. @Jesse

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. You need to include code that shows the effort you've already put in to find a solution yourself. If you don't put in effort, nobody else is going to want to.

Comment: my client asked like this format. @Flydog57

Comment: shall i have to post whole code then you will get i need this requirements. @Jesse

Comment: Include a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Read the link I posted as well. It says what is needed.

Comment: I have updated my question and can you please post your answer now if you know. @Jesse

Comment: I think now you will add answer. @Jesse

Comment: The code you posted still doesn't show an attempt to answer your own question, you're just shoving the phone number into a `SelectListItem`, and this is definitely not minimal. Please read the links I sent.

Comment: It's actually already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188510/how-to-format-a-string-as-a-telephone-number-in-c-sharp)

Comment: you kind information that is not working for me. @Jesse

Comment: i have updated the question above. @Jesse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well how about just writing code to do it

```
string fax="1111111111";

string str2 = $"({fax.Substring(0,3)})-{fax.SubString(3,3)}-{fax.Substring(6,4)}";
```

Comment: ok thanks i will check and update the answer. @pm100

Comment: great answer thanks. @pm100

Comment: please up vote my question because it is giving new way of answer. @pm100

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `var result = string.Format("{0:(###)-###-####}", someValue)` formatting mechanism, then the value you are formatting needs to be a number, not a string.  So you could do something like this:

```
var telNoString = "1111111111";
if (long.TryParse(telNoString, out var telno))
{
    var result = string.Format("{0:(###)-###-####}", telno);
    Debug.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Which will result in `(111)-111-1111` in the debug console.

Comment: @MazharKhan: The reason for your downvotes was that your original question was well below acceptable.  Once you included some code, it was answerable